# Multiple protocols on the same port

Tags: networking, port

From my understanding, Facebook Messenger uses `443` for both HTTP and MQTT (or whatever protocol they may use now) traffic. That seems to be a good strategy, as in some very constrained networks only `80` and  `443`  are allowed. If I wanted to use `443` for all the traffic from our application (HTTP and MQTT/MQTT over WebSockets), how could I achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is only possible if the application that is bound to the port does the protocol switching. Usually there is no way to bind two applications/services to one port.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the [WebSockets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) protocol [initiates its handshake by the client making a special HTTP request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4) and [defaults to using the regular HTTP ports](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.7) (`80/tcp` and `443/tcp` for plain and TLS connections, respectively), it's actually entirely expected that both of these protocols would connect to the same port(s).

I suppose what may be a problem is if you want to have two separate applications, one HTTP application and one WebSockets application, running on the same host using the same port AND the same address (if you can bind them to the same port but different addresses there really is nothing to it).

For such a case I think a WebSockets capable reverse HTTP proxy in front of both applications would make the most sense.
See eg how one can use [Nginx to proxy WebSockets](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) in addition to regular HTTP proxying.